# Creating a unique or primary key constraint for a view

Tags: oracle

i am using a view (country_view) from a TABLE (country) in a different database schema in my project so i have created a SYNONYM (country_syno) to work with and also created a VIEW so i can reference the column (country_id) in my TABLE (person) to the VIEW (country_view) :

```
ALTER VIEW country_view
   ADD CONSTRAINT unq_country_id UNIQUE (country_id);
```

this script is not working showing this error:
 `ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`
i don't know what other options i need to specify.
i also don't know if this is even possible -creating a constraint for a view- and if so is there another option i can try.

Comment: you cant. instead study the view's query and put key/indexws on actual table that you created this view

Comment: the column is indexed (primary key)

Comment: can i instead create a view from a different database schema?

Comment: there are any performance issue ? thats why you want to create key/index ?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE), the only option to add constraint on view is in `disable` mode. This *may* add some semantics to your model, but constraint is not checked, because view is purely virtual object that does not contain any data. To enforce uniqueness you need to specify a constraint for the base tables.